# Low memory node image resizing/S3 option

Tags: javascript, node.js

Looking for some ideas on this. I currently use Imager - perfect functionality except that I get memory issues on larger images - I use NodeJitsu and have very little memory to play with. I am looking for another solution that will not load the entire image in memory - need to do multiple size and upload to S3 (cloudfiles would work to). I found this

- https://npmjs.org/package/image-resize-s3 - deprecated/no gif support
- https://github.com/funraiseme/simgr - no docs, not even sure how that works with S3

Ideas?

Comment: Hahaha those are my libs. Image resize s3 sucks as it takes way too much memory. I don't recommend resizing more than one image at a single time as it will kill your server. Currently, simgr works by uploading the original to s3 and grabbing a single resized version at a time. This is better for the server as you generally don't need all the sizes at one time. I'll add docs soon.

Comment: docs added to simgr :)

Comment: Cool - one thing I am not clear on simgr is the storage location of the resized images - anyway to get them to S3?

Comment: it doesnt store it in s3. i just cache it at the CDN. you can upload it to S3 if you want.

Comment: `image-resizing` npm package resizes images by using Node.js stream API, without loading everything into memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can offload this task to a (serverless) cloud function, each resizing operation will run in a separate Docker container that shutdowns instantly after the HTTP request is complete.

Here is an example, that uses [`image-resizing`](https://github.com/kriasoft/image-resizing) Node.js/NPM package:

```
$ npm install image-resizing --save
```

```js
const { createHandler } = require("image-resizing");

module.exports.img = createHandler({
  // Where the source images are located.
  // E.g. gs://s.example.com/image.jpg
  sourceBucket: "s.example.com",
  // Where the transformed images needs to be stored.
  // E.g. gs://c.example.com/image__w_80,h_60.jpg
  cacheBucket: "c.example.com",
});
```

[image]

```
https://example.com/image.jpg
```

[image]

```
https://example.com/w_120,h_120,c_fill/image.jpg
```